# rx javascript periodic event ignore until handled first

Tags: javascript, reactive-extensions-js

maybe I missed purpose of RX for javascript library, but I think it should handle this scenario nicely.

I would like to have periodic events generated through observable. Subscriber should take first event and make ajax request. Other events while this one is processed should be ignored. After completion should observer receive next generated event.

Any suggestions? Many thanks.